# How to set DataContext with binding?

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a DockPanel set up like this

```
<Window ... >
<DockPanel x:Name="myDock" DataContext="{Binding HonapokList}" >
```

Inside the Dockpanel there is a TextBox, like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbCount" Text="{Binding Path=Count,Mode=OneWay}" />
</DockPanel>   
</Window>
```

This is how i set up HonapokList, so it's basically a List String>

```
public List<String> HonapokList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HonapokList = new List<string>();           
        Honapok.ItemsSource = HonapokList;
        HonapokList.Add("January");
        HonapokList.Add("February");
        HonapokList.Add("March");
    }
```

I want my textbox to display the number of elements in the HonapokList ( 3 in this example), however nothing is in it. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Window` doesn't have a default `DataContext`, but it looks like you're assuming it to be set to itself. You can set it to do that either in the constructor:

```
DataContext = this;
```

or in the XAML:

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

You're also going to need to change `HonapokList` to be a property, not a field as it is now, in order to bind to it.

Comment: What does this c sharp code equals in XAML?
MyStackPanel.DataContext = MyProperty;

Comment: It depends where you're calling that and what DataContexts you're using in the XAML but something like: <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=MyProperty}"/>

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can bind with `Properties` only and not with `fields`. So, make `HonapokList` a property -

```
public List<String> HonapokList { get; }
```

Secondly, change your xaml to look up for the property in your `Window` class using `RelativeSource`-

```
<DockPanel x:Name="myDock">
   <TextBox x:Name="tbCount"
            Text="{Binding Path=HonapokList.Count, Mode=OneWay,
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                    AncestorType=Window}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

OR

Set the `DataContext` on your window

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

and then you can do like this -

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbCount"
         Text="{Binding Path=HonapokList.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```